# Can I respond to a Flyout flying out and then assign values to its controls programatically?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, listboxitems, flyout, xaml-binding

I know the canonical way to assign data to controls in the XAML world is to use binding like so in the XAML file:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstbxPhotosets" ItemsSource="{Binding photosets}" . . .
```

...but I would just as soon assign it in code, something like this:

```
private void flyout_FlewOpen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs reargs)
{
    sender.lstbxPhotosets.Items = GetPhotosets();
}

internal static List<String> GetPhotosets()
{
    List<String> psets = new List<string>();
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT photosetName FROM PhotraxBaseData ORDER BY photosetName";
        psets = db.Query("sql"); // <= pseudocode; this doesn't compile
    }
    return psets;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what event does the Flyout expose that I can tap into (no pun intended)?

Can I access controls on the Flyout via "sender", or...???

**Note:** This is a Windows 8.1 app, and a native (not Callista) flyout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the Flyout.[Opening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.opening.aspx) or [Opened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.opened.aspx) event. The Flyout should be the sender, and you can use [FrameworkElement.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) or [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) on the Flyout's [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.content.aspx) to find child controls of the Flyout. Data binding will probably be cleaner and easier.

--Rob

Comment: All I really want to do is ask the user for a string - what they want to name the set of photos they've selected. I must be overlooking the obvious way to do it, because there must be some rather straightforward way to do it.